# Google Chrome view saved form data

Tags: google-chrome

I know how to delete saved form data in Chrome, but I'd like to be able to see all of the entries stored for fields.

When I type `a` into a form, I get a list of a few items that I have typed before in that field which begin with `a`.

I would like to see a complete list, though.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Chrome stores that information in a SQLite DB file. And the following procedure will help you search it in there:

1. Download some SQLite client (e.g. [command-line shell program](https://www.sqlite.org/download.html) or [DB Browser for SQLite](http://sqlitebrowser.org/))
2. Close Google Chrome (otherwise you will get "database is locked" error)
3. Open the SQLite DB file located at `%userprofile%\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Web Data`
     (on some systems, the file instead may be named `Chrome Web Data`)
4. Click the `Execute SQL` tab and then copy the following query:

   ```
    select *
    from autofill
    where name in (
      select name
      from autofill
      where value_lower like 'one-data-entry-of-you'
    );
   ```
5. Replace `one-data-entry-of-you` for some text you know you have entered in that field. But try to use text that is not used in many fields: the more peculiar the better, because if the text replaced is used on many fields you will see all the entries for those many fields at the same time.
6. Click `Execute Query`.

Comment: Thanks! I used the SQLite Manager Addon in Firefox and it worked great.

Comment: Or you can open your file at `C:\Users\YourUserHere\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Web Data`. Where "Web Data" is the filename.

Comment: I got error `Invalid file format`

Comment: I also got `Invalid file format` while Chrome was open. Closing Chrome completely allowed it to be opened in a SQLite browser. I've now removed the unwanted entries. (I also discovered that Shift+Delete removes them from within Chrome.)

Comment: For macosx users: `%user%/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Profile ?/Web Data` or `%user%/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Guest Profile/Web Data`. Also sqlite has been moved to https://github.com/sqlitebrowser/sqlitebrowser/releases/tag/v3.8.0

Comment: And on Linux, it's `~/.config/google-chrome/Default` ([from](http://www.chromium.org/user-experience/user-data-directory), [via](http://superuser.com/a/884033/106852))

Comment: Updating to the latest SqLite Database Browser version solved the invalid file format error.

Comment: How do I find the key used to encrypt the database?

Comment: @jj_ chrome must be closed. if you can't close it, make a copy of the file via terminal like `cp "Web Data" "Web Data Copy"` and it'll open without prompting for a password.

Comment: I forget what I input on a specific webpage and the webpage is not available now. Would you please tell me, what SQL query should I execute, so I can get auto-fill items filtered by the specific site? Thanks!

Comment: `~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default/Web Data` on the **Mac**. (Be sure to shut down Chrome before trying to open this database.)

Comment: Hey, can you tell me how to interpret the date_created column of the table inside this database? It's a large number, so I am guessing it is the number of seconds that has elapsed from a fixed point in time

Comment: @VishalSubramanyam I don't remember now. But I think is likely a [UNIX Epoch time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time). You might try to convert it directly with the SQL function: `date(date_created, 'unixepoch', 'localtime')`

Comment: @VishalSubramanyam But I'm not sure if it's stored as UTC or directly in localtime. So maybe is just: `date(date_created, 'unixepoch')`. You might check what 'unixepoch' and 'localtime' does at [sqlite date function documentation](https://sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html)

Answer (score 2):

By design it only does the most recent few.
If you want something that'll do this you're gonna need something like [Lazarus](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/loljledaigphbcpfhfmgopdkppkifgno).

Comment: As of this writing, the Lazarus link is broken (404 error).