# See all autofill data

Tags: google-chrome

In Google chrome when I start typing in a text box I get auto completion for things I have use din the past, this however is only for the current letter. Is there a way I can see all of the auto complete data Google Chrome has for this text box?

[image]

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Google Chrome stores a lot of stuff in SQLite databases. To look at this data, download and run [SQLite Browser](http://sqlitebrowser.org/).

The instructions are for Windows systems. On other platforms, use the [location of user data directories specific to that OS](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/docs/user_data_dir.md).

1. Open `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Web Data`
2. If Chrome is currently running, you won't be able to access the file, so first make a copy of it by running:

   ```
   copy "%LOCALAPPDATA%\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Web Data" "%LOCALAPPDATA%\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\WebData-working"
   ```
3. Open `WebData-working` in SQLite Browser, switch to the **Browse Data** tab and select `autofill` from the **Table** dropdown list.
   [image: Google Chrome autofill data]

Comment: I have about 1000 entries in this data base. How can I get the ones specific to that field?

Comment: @Vader Find out the input field name by looking at the page source (e.g. 'username') then execute this SQL query in the `Execute SQL` tab: `SELECT * FROM autofill WHERE name = 'username';` where `username` is the name of the HTML form field.

Comment: @Vader I understand this is an old post, but hey. 
There are text fields with the label "Filter" above the first row and under the table headers. Each text field will filter the column it's located in. 
Filter means It will search through your 1000 and only show entries that contain the text you entered. 
You simply click on one of the fields and enter your search text and it will filter the contents for you. The result will be shown as you type.

Comment: Tks, I could use it to modify the `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\History` database, I ran `SELECT * FROM keyword_search_terms WHERE lower_term LIKE '%media%';` to find the entries concerning `media` and delete them with `DELETE FROM keyword_search_terms WHERE lower_term LIKE '%media%';` which effectively changed the url proposed by chrome when typing `me`