# How to export Chrome Autofill form data?

Tags: google-chrome, export, auto-form-fill

I'd like to remove one user profile from Chrome web browser, but before I'd like to export its *Autofill form data*. For example, here is the question [how to export browsing history](https://superuser.com/q/602252/87805). So if it's not possible to export this data from the web browser it-self, I'm looking for some similar method by directly exporting from the files.

How this can be achieved? Ideally on macOS, but any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: Do you only need the usernames/passwords?

Comment: _Autofill form data_ is different to password data.

Answer (score 4):

After doing some more reading and realizing you meant autofill, yes. The autofill database is contained in `~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome` in the file `Web Data`. Using a SQLite browser such as [DB Browser](http://sqlitebrowser.org/) will allow you to view the data.

See here: [See all autofill data](https://superuser.com/a/884033/719115)

Answer (score 2):

Follow up on @plttn 's tip. It seems the file `Web Data` location in Windows 10 is under `%APPDATA%\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\`, subfolder `Default` or maybe in another user profiles - I suspect depending on the identity/sign in used in the browser.

For me, the `Web Data` file under the `Default` folder worked to correct entries that Chrome had saved incorrectly.